# High CPU usage on Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, cpu-usage

Tensorflow process uses 80% of CPU capacity.
And it uses only 8% of GPU capacity.
So, I checked the callstack of the tensorflow process and found out some weird threads like as the image below.
I think 'XentEigenImpl' in the top of the callstack is 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2'.
However, I can not understand why 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2' calls 'strcat' many times.
There are many threads those have same callstack and cause the CPU usage problem.
How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

[image]